# Sending Notification in Modal Popup to Users

Tags: notifications, modal-popup

This question can be little different than you expect. I am wondering how would I show notification modal popup on a user's browser window whenever they come online and whichever the website they connect, and suppose I am the internet provider of these users. They don't have to download anything to their computer and they can see the modal popup notification window whenever they come online.

How can I do that ? Nope, I am not asking the codes, just a path to follow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, actually some companies use this method to notify their users or simply show their users some freaky promotions about their new systems, billing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to proxy all their HTTP connection and inject a small piece of javascript.
If that JS detects it's in a top frame, it polls the server to know if there is a popup to display or not. If there is, display it.

Comment: Isn't that a little bit easy ? :)